# alphabetizing array of objects by string (name)

Tags: c#, sorting

I am VERY new to programming, and am learning C#. Week 4!

Writing program asking for user input for:

- Friends name
- Phone
- Month of Birth
- Day
- Year of birth.

Creating as an array of objects and using the IComparable to enable object comparison.
Need to sort objects by string, alphabetically, and I think I have all the rest of the code except getting the string to compare.  Here's what I have for the `IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)`:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
{
    int returnVal;

    Friend temp = (Friend)o;
    if(this.Name > temp.Name)
        returnVal = 1;
    else
        if(this.Name < temp.Name)
            returnVal = -1;
        else returnVal = 0;
    return returnVal;
}
```

The error I receive when compiling is:

> CS0019 Operator'>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Instructor is not much help, text doesn't synthesize this contingency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delegate to `String.CompareTo`:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o) {
    Friend temp = (Friend)o;

    return this.Name.CompareTo(temp.Name);
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that this performs “[case-sensitive and culture-sensitive comparison using the current culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx)”, which may or may not be what's required.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a couple language features you are probably not used to, but does make like a little easier:

```
people = people.OrderBy(person => person.Name).ToList();
```

Used like:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var people = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    people.Add(new Person { Name = rnd.Next().ToString() });

//remember, this provides an alphabetical, not numerical ordering,
//because name is a string, not numerical in this example.
people = people.OrderBy(person => person.Name).ToList();

people.ForEach(person => Console.WriteLine(person.Name));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Google LINQ [and remember to add 'using System.Linq;'] and Lambda's.